# Node.js worker for vsivsi/meteor-job-collection fails on job.done(): "Exception while invoking method 'jobs_jobDone' Error: Match error..."

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, jobs, worker

I'm writing a Meteor app that adds jobs to a queue that are to be processed by one or more external workers. I'm using vsivsi/meteor-job-collection (https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection) and everything worked fine when I was (initially) processing jobs using method-based (i.e., non external) workers from within the Meteor app itself (which queues, creates and manages the jobs).

However, I want an external process, i.e., a Node.js program (not even a Meteor app) to listen for and subsequently process posted jobs instead and saw that this is indeed possible at https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection#quick-example (third code block; "node.js Worker") - after all, this enables a more generic and Meteor-agnostic job-processing approach.

I created a separate Node.js program, successfully connected it to my running Meteor app using dpp, ddp-login and meteor-job and started the job listener in exactly the same fashion as I originally did within the Meteor app (when using method-based workers), but I get the following inexplicable error (only) when calling job.done() (other job methods seem to work flawlessly):

**"Exception while invoking method 'jobs_jobDone' Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation"**

The code:

```
var DDP = require('ddp');
var DDPlogin = require('ddp-login');
var Job = require('meteor-job');
var ddp = new DDP({
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3000,
    use_ejson: true
});

Job.setDDP(ddp);
ddp.connect(connectCB);

function connectCB(err) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    var options = { //Needed to be able to log in; METEOR_TOKEN is set as an environment variable and this works fine.
        env: 'METEOR_TOKEN',
        method: 'account',
        account: null,  
        pass: null,     
        retry: 5,       
        plaintext: false
    };
    DDPlogin(ddp, options, ddpLoginCB);
}

function ddpLoginCB(err) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    Job.processJobs('jobs', 'dataGatherJob', {
        concurrency: 8,
        pollInterval: 250
    }, processJobsCB);
}

function processJobsCB(job, cb) {
    //This is where the actual work gets done; this callback works fine,
    //is triggered when my Meteor app adds a new job, and the job object
    //conforms to my expectations; just some example calls on/usages of the
    //job object that work fine and are reactively updated and handled by my
    //Meteor app:
    //console.log(job); //Works fine.
    //job.progress(50, 100); //Works fine.
    //job.fail(); //Works fine.
    job.done(); //Causes the Meteor-app (server) to generate an "Exception while invoking method 'jobs_jobDone' Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation" error.
    cb(); 
}
```

I do not understand why this is happening. The job id is identical to the one in the actual Mongo collection (the queue uses a Mongo collection to manage jobs) set by the server (I checked this) and besides that, other job operations (e.g., job.fail()) do work. I furthermore reset the "autopublish" and "insecure" packages for my Meteor app intermittently just to be sure that they are not causing the problem and this was not the case.

Any thoughts on this?

Many thanks in advance,
Danny.

Comment: Looks to me like you need to pass a result into `.done()` https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection#jobdoneresult-options-callback---anywhere

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought so as well, but that doesn't seem to make a difference: when using the job.done("Done!") example at https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-job#j-done-result-options-callback the error is the same; I posted it on the library's Github page as well and in the meantime I simply delegated a job.done-call to the server by remotely calling a Meteor method through DDP, i.e.: ddp.call('setJobDone', [job._doc._id], function(err, result) { ... }, function() { ... }) as in https://www.npmjs.com/package/ddp#example. This gets the job done for now (quite literally).

Comment: Yeah, saw that you posted an issue - hopefully they can get that straightened out. Considering that those `Match` methods are on the other ddp methods that work, not sure why it would fail... might have been introduced in this commit from a week ago: https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection/commit/74eae63f6fefe9e0eadee52967a8e4747aade32d

Comment: It looks like this is a version mismatch issue between job-collection and meteor-job. See discussion on the related issue on github: https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection/issues/98

Comment: Once I confirm with the OP that using an incompatible (newer) version of the client with an older server is the issue, I'll write an Answer here explaining the relationship between job-collection and meteor-job more clearly.